# Getting Connectionstring values from Other config file in subfolders and add the connectionstring to the root app.config file

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I am using a windows application in which I have config files (`dev.config`, `prod.config`, `uat.config`) located in multiple folders such as `dev`, `prod`, `uat`. I want to get the particular config file values such as `connectionstrings` based on the certain condition from a particular folder and I want to add the corresponding `connectionstrings` in the root `app.config` file. Then I need to fetch data based on the added connection string. Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

What you *can* do pretty easily is to *externalize* your connection strings (we tend to put them into `App_Data\config`, since that folder is protected by IIS and nothing from that folder will be returned when trying to browse it)

So in your *main* `web.config`, you would have something like this:

```
<connectionStrings configSource="App_Data\config\dev.config" />
```

and then you go to testing, you just change that to

```
<connectionStrings configSource="App_Data\config\uat.config" />
```

and in your individual config files, you just have that one section:

`dev.config`:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="SomeName"
        connectionString="server=.;database=test;integrated Security=SSPI;"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
   ......
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could load a custom config file based on a condition using ExeConfigurationFileMap and ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration().

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap configFileMap = ExeConfigurationFileMap("path/to/custom.config");
System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configFileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None)
```

When you have the config object, you can then pick the given section you need, in your case the `connectionstrings`.

```
ConnectionStringsSection connectionStrings = config.ConnectionStrings;
```

You could then load whichever config file you want based on the conditions you want, and pick out the parts you'd like.

More info about the [ConnectionStringsSection with a short example (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.connectionstringssection(v=vs.110).aspx).